# Problem solving this system of equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have got a system of equations and I want to solve for x and y. However, I can't seem to be able to solve it.

$$\begin{cases}
2x+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + 1}} = 0 \\
\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}} = 0 
\end{cases}$$

I've tried to put x as subject of formula but then, we still get $x^2$ in the square root. I also tried rationalizing but no luck.

Comment: these aren't equations, there are no equals signs anywhere!

Comment: Edited them. I accidentally submitted without finishing my post.

Comment: It is clear $y=0,x=0$

Comment: @math110 This is the only one I got as well just by pure guess. However, how can I be sure that there are no other pair of values $(x,y)$ that satisfy the equations?

Comment: The second one automatically solves as $y=0$.  Then you can get one solution for the first one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the 2nd equation you can derive $y=0$. Then the first equation simplifies to

$x(2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}) = 0$. The second factor can't be $0$, hence $x=0$ aswell.

Comment: Are we allowed to just derive y = 0? That's the part where I'm stuck. I'm not sure when it's allowed to just let $y = 0$ since we have $y^2$ in the denominator.

Comment: The denominator in the second equation is always distinct from $0$.  So we can multiply the whole equation with the denominator without changing the solutions.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.